# Undefined offset in array - But I know it's in there

Tags: php

I have an array (or associative array), with keys and values.
Then, when trying to read one of the keys, which IS in the array, I get an "undefined offset" notice.

I have two examples where it happened. One was "exploding" a string like "AAA|BBB|CCC", using `|` as the separator, then trying to read the resulting array at position 1.
`var_dump()` correctly shows an array having offsets 0 to 2, with the correct values. But I still get the notice.

Another example is I get an array (from an AJAX call, I json_decode it, etc), then I typed the following code:

```
foreach (array_keys($myDecodedArray) as $k) {
    $value = $myDecodedArray[$k];
    someOtherCode();
}
```

I had that damn notice appear when trying to read `$myDecodedArray[$k]`, although php itself had just told me the key existed !

So, I solved that last case by going

```
foreach ($myDecodedArray as $k => $value) {
    someOtherCode();
}
```

but still, this is extremely annoying, and makes no sense to me.

Any of you run into that problem before?
Do you have any information about what could cause that?

[EDIT]
Rahul Meshram's suggestion (which I upvoted in the comments) solved my second problem case.
However, the first case still happens (exploding a string into an array, then trying to access that array's values by their numeric keys).
The keys ARE numeric (gettype returns 'integer', var_dump on that key shows an integer too, with the right value), but trying to access $explodedArray[1] still results in that notice being displayed, despite $explodedArray having keys 0, 1, and 2, with associated values.

Comment: Kindly share your code

Comment: Noone here can help you unless you __show code__ which causes errors.

Comment: Trying to. The site tells me it's badly indented, even though I put it in "&lt;pre&gt;" or "&lt;code&gt;" tags... The reversed quotes seem to work, though. Please bear with me.

Comment: Cut and paste the code, select it all and press the `{}` button above the editing window. That will indent it appropriately.

Comment: `foreach ($myDecodedArray as $k => $value)` is what you actually want...

Comment: `$k` is not a __key__, it is __value__.

Comment: Thanks, Nick, but as you can see in my whole question, I already have it.
Though, when PHP itself tells me a given key is in a given array, I fully expect to be able to access the value behind said key. Shouldn't I ?

Comment: can you show us how you did json_decode of that ajax array? Can you show us your sample array?

Comment: u_mulder: my bad, corrected my question. I had written it correctly the first time, then it got lost, and I forgot that when I retyped it.

I asked PHP for the ARRAY KEYS, not the values :)

Comment: To decode the Json, I used:
`$rows  = (Array) json_decode($this->input->post('rows'));`

Yes, this is some CodeIgniter method, here.

Comment: can you show sample json ?

Comment: `$rows = json_decode($this->input->post('rows'), true);` try this instead of your snippet and check and let me know if that error is still there

Comment: Rahul: Thanks, this worked and solved the problem. (at least, the second one, where array_keys were'nt recognized)